# Disconnect Internet connection on given time

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection, automation

I need to disconnect my Internet connection on a given time (to avoid exceeding my Internet usage time limit), without shutting down the computer.

How can I do that?

Comment: Windows has this ability built into it.  There are also parental software that might meet your requirements although I doubt those are free.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure about Windows having the built-in ability. I think it has the ability to disconnect *at* a certain time, but I don't think it can do it based on a duration. It seems the OP is asking to do it after a certain elapsed time.

Comment: schedule a batch with `ipconfig /release *` or similar? i'm not getting the question 100%

Comment: @Ramhound Windows doesn't have the built-in ability to manage system-wide IP traffic on a time-basis. Might you be referring to parental control features? That only affects the local user and particular traffic types. Services and SYSTEM level processes can still send/receive IP traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Windows (any version), you would schedule a task to run a command to release the IP using the task scheduler.

[image: TS]

[image: TASK]

Comment: Wouldn't this *not* be permanent in the case the DHCP server or router got power cycled? I think disabling the adapter would be a better option. Substituting `ipconfig` with `netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled`?

Comment: good call, I think that would work better too!

Answer (score 1):

[This utility](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/tbbmeter.html) from thinkbroadband will not disconnect your internet but it can be set to activate an alert/alarm to tell you that you are close to your limit

> ```
> Monitor the Internet usage of your computer in real time- see data being sent and received
> See daily, monthly and weekly statistics on how much you use and when
> Set alarms to protect yourself from exceeding your monthly usage allowance, or a fair use limit
> Pre-defined alarm profiles available to download
> Use the stopwatch to record how fast your downloads are
> Run a ping stream to graph how your latency varies
> Background tests to measure your broadband performance
> Graph your usage from multiple household computers
> Analyse performance by protocol (e.g. VoIP, p2p, etc.)
> ```